# CSS — responsive horizontal nav with sub nav below

Tags: html, css

I have this horizontal nav which works how I want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/rnSY4/

When the window is made smaller the main nav items collapse pushing the sub nav down.

I would prefer it if the sub nav UL was a child of one of the main nav LIs but I can't work out how to do it. All the solutions I've found involve adding `position: absolute` to the sub nav which means it won't move down when the main nav collapses (I also need all the content below the sub nav to move down as well).

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: and how shoud the other elements of main nav behave, when the window is smaller?

Comment: Look at the Dropdown Nav examples in Twitter Bootstrap for ideas: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs -- you'l

Comment: should behave exactly as my example, one nav below the other. But with the sub Ul nested in an LI in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to remove the overflow:hidden from the parent UL, set the top level LI to have position:relative (so that the drop downs position relative to them not the header) and then apply styles to the drop down.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnSY4/1/

For cross browser compliance you will need to load some Javascript to add an on hover event to the LI so that you can show the drop down on IE6.

Comment: Thanks for trying but that doesn't really solve my problem. I need it to look and work exactly like my example but with the sub UL nested in the LI. In your test the sub nav is attached to its container LI, I need it to sit below the main UL as a whole and adjust its position when needed.

Comment: That seems like quite an unusual circumstance. The fact you are using a list suggests some interest in being semantically correct, at least on a basic level and as such you would surely want your code to be correct in a hierarchal sense? How comes you need it to be like this? I am curious now :)

Comment: I'd like it to look like my example on large screens and then revert to a more basic vertical list (with nested sub lists) on mobile. So would like the HTML to follow a nested list structure and then create the different layouts with CSS. If my layout isn't possible I might just work on a JS solution which breaks the sub list out of the main list on non-mobile screens.